# How to use DataBinding with LiveData inside RecyclerView

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

So DataBinding can now use LiveData in its binding. As part of this, we also have to set to the Data Binding the life cycle like so:

```
SampleLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(this, R.layout.sample_layout)
binding.setLifeCycleOwner(this)
```

My question is what is the proper way to set this lifecycle owner inside recyclerview? Or even more appropriately, do we need to set the LifeCyclerOwner when using data binding inside recyclerview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to set `LifeCycleOwner` to your data-binding. For this purpose you need to pass `Activity`/`Fragment` to your `RecyclerView.Adapter` as `LifeCycleOwner` interface and set it when you create binding in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onCreateViewHolder()`.
You also can use your own implementation of `LifeCycleOwner`

Comment: how can I ensure that I wont leak the activity or fragment by doing this?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones it's one of [advantages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata) of using `LiveData`: **No memory leaks**. *Observers are bound to `Lifecycle` objects and clean up after themselves when their associated lifecycle is destroyed*

Comment: Does that mean I just pass the LifeCycleOwner in the Adapter constructor like so? SampleAdapter(LifeCyclerOwner lifecyclerOwner, List<SomeType> list)? don't I have to release the reference of the lifecyclerOwner to avoid memory leak? Or Since the Activity's View or Fragment View is destroyed with the activity, so is the Adapter and therefore no leak. Is that right?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones yes. If your adapter have reference only from activity, it  will be in memory until activity will be garbage collected. If you have external reference to adapter - you, probably, have memory leak

Comment: Noted. I would really appreciate it if you post some sample code. Thank you very much.